# How to view path before command line in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, server

Whenever I ssh as root on my EC2 instance (AWS) I see

> ubuntu@[ip-address]:[path]$

When I switch to my own made super user I see:

> myUser@[ip-address]:[path]$

But when I ssh as myUser I only see

> $

How and where can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find what you need on [this site](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

It explains how to edit PS1 value.

> Prompt is control via a special shell variable. You need to set PS1, PS2, PS3 and PS4 variable. If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.